# Gibbs sampler for Dirichlet Process concentration parameter

Tags: bayesian, sampling, gibbs, dirichlet-process

I am trying to implement a Gibbs sampler for Hierarchical Dirichlet process, but I cannot seem to correctly estimate the concentration parameters. I therefore started testing just this part of a sampler, and found an issue that I don't believe was mentioned here before. Then again, I do suspect I'm just making some silly mistake - all inputs highly appreciated.

**Dirichlet process:**

I first simulate a Dirichlet process, particularly the number of components $k$ that is generated in the process, which depends on the number of observations $n$ and the concentration parameter $\alpha$.

A classic explanation of this is the Chinese restaurant process, i.e. each observation can be though of as a customer entering a restaurant. The customer joins a table with probability proportional to the number of customers already sitting at this table, or sits at an empty (new) table with probability proportional to the concentration parameter $\alpha$. So for the $i$-th observation the probability for being assigned to a particular component can be expressed as:
$$p(t_i = t) = \begin{cases} \frac{n_t}{\sum_t (n_t) + \alpha}, & \mbox{for } t \leq t_{\text{max}} \\ \frac{\alpha}{\sum_t (n_t) + \alpha}, & \mbox{for } t = t_{\text{max}}+1 \end{cases} $$
where $n_t$ is the number of observations already assigned to component $t$ and $t_{\text{max}}$ is the current number of components. Important for later:

$$ \mathbb{E}(k) \approx \alpha \ln\Big(\frac{\alpha+n}{\alpha}\Big)$$

or more generally - the number of components $k$ increases with both $\alpha$ and $n$.

**Inference about the concentration parameter:**

Now, having simulated the Dirichlet process I have the number of observations $n$, the number of components $k$ and know the true concentration parameter $\alpha$. I would like to test if my sampler is able to identify the true $\alpha$. I am using a method proposed by [Escobar and West (1995)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/281B-spring04/readings/escobar-west.pdf) - eq. (13-14), particularly the form used by [Teh et al. (2005)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf) - appendix A, and [Heinrich (2008)](http://www.arbylon.net/publications/ilda.pdf) - eq. (18-19). While the form differs a bit and to be honest I don't see how they are equivalent, I tested both distributions and they are indeed the same.

Assuming a gamma prior, $\alpha \sim \text{Gamma}(a, b)$, the sampling procedure first samples two auxiliary variables based on the old value of $\alpha$, and then uses them to sample the new value for $\alpha$.

$$u \sim \text{Bern}\Big(\frac{n}{n+\alpha}\Big) $$
$$v \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha + 1, n) $$
$$\alpha \sim \text{Gamma}(a + K - 1 + u, b - \ln v) $$

**Problem:**

This sampler provides absolutely wrong estimates for $\alpha$. Example: I simulate a DP with $n=1000$, $\alpha=1$, resulting with $k=7$ - a number very close to the expected value. I then run the sampler, with prior $\text{Gamma}(1,1)$ (doesn't really have much impact with such number of observations) for 1000 iterations, **starting from the true value for $\alpha$**. The sampler then quickly achieves stability, with average $\hat{\alpha}\approx 35$. Utterly wrong.

I feel like I'm missing some crucial part of the method. Especially since it seems to me like the formula for the sampler makes no sense - here's my rationale:

For a fixed value of $k$ my estimate of $\alpha$ should **decrease** in $n$ (if I have a huge sample with very few components, that tells me my $\alpha$ is tiny). Yet if $n \to \infty$, then $u \sim \text{Bern}(\frac{n}{n+\alpha})$ is almost surely $1$, while $v \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha + 1, n)$ is almost surely $0$ since $\mathbb{E}(v) = \frac{\alpha + 1}{\alpha + 1 + n}$.

Then the expected value of my new $\alpha$ is:
$$ \mathbb{E}(\alpha) = (a+k-1+u) (b - \ln v) \to \infty$$
because of "$\ln 0$". So for huge number of observations I will have huge estimate of $\alpha$. Running the Gibbs sampler with fixed $k$ and initial $\alpha$, while increasing $n$ confirms that suspicion. Now, this doesn't really make any sense, does it? Or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

So just as I thought, it was a silly mistake. While the authors repeatedly refer to the second Gamma distribution parameter as **scale**, it's actually the **rate** parameter (so to write in accordance with e.g. `NumPy` standards, $\alpha \sim \text{Gamma}(a+k-1+u,\frac{1}{b-\ln v})$. I'm a bit ashamed of how long it took me to realise that, but I'll leave the question on the very off chance someone has the same problem.